# Strange behavior from VideoView on AndroidTV

Tags: android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-tv

Be ready for a really strange and unusual behavior!! So basically I have an application that plays different videos in a slideshow format. Each video/image has a duration and once its finished the next media file is queued up and played. When I run the application on any mobile phone or Android TV BOX (Chinese TVbox) it works fine. However, and here's the unusual part... When I run it on an official Android TV, the content plays correctly the first time, when its finished it loops back to the first media file (all good so far) but if the content has a video and its located before the last media file I only see a black screen for that file.

Here's an example just to explain it a bit more.

Files:
- Vid-1 (Duration 5sec)
- Vid-2 (Duration 10sec)
- Vid-3 (Duration 7sec)
- Img-4 (Duration 5sec)

The first time I start the App, All media listed above will play normally. After that once it loops back to Vid-1, all media plays normally except Vid-3. I get black screen on Vid-3.

Anyone has ever faced a similar issue? Sadly, I got no errors or logs to share as there is nothing there.